# Gitlab CI & Rails Postgres crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to configure CI on Gitlab CI and get this error

```
$ rake db:create
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"runner", "database"=>"ems"}
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Is your postgres service running ? you can start it by `sudo service postgresql start` .

Comment: Got this one on `sudo service postgresql start` ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1

Comment: Do show your .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: ```
image: ruby:2.4
services:
  - postgres
  - redis
before_script:
  - sudo service postgresql start
  - cp config/database.yml.gitlabci config/database.yml
  - bundle install
  - RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create
  - RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
tests:
  script: 'bundle exec rspec'
styleguide:
  script: 'bundle exec rubocop'
variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: dbdb
  POSTGRES_USER: runner
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service defined in .gitlab-ci.yml is [a seperate docker instance](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services) not a local service. You need to update your db configuration to point to a host named `postgres`